# Avoid MFC LOC DLL

Tags: mfc, localization

I'm working on an MFC app that has been localized to multiple languages. It links to MFC dynamically and if the target system has the MFC LOC DLLs installed it automatically uses those DLLs as expected. However, on some of these OSs we have users who prefer English, is there a way for me to force it to use the English DLL instead of the translated MFC LOC DLL?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of systems you meant (other than Windows which is obvious) but maybe the users that prefer English (I doubt everyone in given country...) can set their preferred UI Language in Regional Settings to English?  Other than that, you'd need to write custom loader to load DLL in preferred language rather than OS default. Could you post this bit of code that loads your localization libraries? Especially with respect to Locale Detection (I wonder what code you use to get to know LCID)?

Answer (score 0):

The MFC LOC mechanism is IMHO terrible. It should be avoided by all means because it causes more harm than good

By its unability to use more than one translation, as you experienced it, MFC LOC deserves a good place in the Hall of Shame of our industry. Just think of all these apps who caused other unrelated MFC-based app to appear partially translated.

That's why I believe it's better to provide the translations for MFC resources in your own resource DLLs.

Disclaimer: My ad follows ;-)

[appTranslator](http://www.apptranslator.com) is your friend to translate your MFC app. It automatically translate the MFC part of your resources in up to 27 languages. It automatically builds your resource DLLs. And much more...

/End of ad

And this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/LanguageMenu.aspx) of mine provides ready-to-use code to support loading of resource DLLs and support for a language menu. OK, this was not your question but I thought it may help. Oh, and it's out of the disclaimer since it's free ;-)

Comment: If I link dynamically to MFC how do I prevent it from loading LOC DLLs already on the system? Is the only reasonable solution to statically link to MFC?

Comment: If you install the MFC dll side-by-side with your app, it won't look for a shared MFC loc dll.

Comment: I've tried to use the MFC side by side, both using Merge Modules and private assemblies in the local directory and both still manage to find the LOC DLL installed by the full redistributable install that was installed prior.

Comment: which verison of VS and MFC do you use?

Comment: Looks like this appTranslator's website is not working anymore. Isn't it on Github or somewhere else by a chance? Thanks!

Comment: @juice, sorry no, I never took the time to put the code on GitHub or other. It's now lost on a HDD somewhere deep in my basement...